# Virus disturbing my audio

Tags: windows-vista

i had a desktop.ini virus on my computer. I managed to get rid of it (i think) but now my Mcafee firewall will not stay on for more than 3 secs before it turns off again. Also something is freezing my computer for a few secs when a window is open, also my audio goes in and out when watching videos and listening to music. I figured out that it only happens when i connect to the internet. I have to restart my PC and quickly disconnect the internet if i want to listen to music. also i have vista

Comment: Most likely is still infected...http://superuser.com/questions/100360/computer-is-infected-by-a-virus-or-a-malware-what-do-i-do-now/157533#157533

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How can I remove malicious spyware, malware, adware, viruses, trojans or rootkits from my PC?](https://superuser.com/questions/100360/how-can-i-remove-malicious-spyware-malware-adware-viruses-trojans-or-rootkit)

Answer (score 0):

To make sure that you have fully removed the virus from your computer, I recommend that you try downloading and running [McAfee's Stinger utility](http://www.mcafee.com/us/downloads/free-tools/how-to-use-stinger.aspx).

After the virus has been removed, you may have damaged Windows Vista files. You should run the System File Checker to see if Vista can repair the damaged files. For instructions, see [this article](http://www.ehow.com/how_2149149_system-files-windows-vista-home.html).

Comment: To make sure you have fully removed a malware, you need to [reinstall the OS](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc512587.aspx) or compare every single file to a known-good baseline.